# Shared object missing from pin tool

Tags: linux, makefile, intel-pin

When I compile my pin tool and run `ldd` on the pin tool shared object the shared objects libxed.so, libpin3dwarf.so, libdl-dynamic.so, libstlport-dynamic.so, and libc-dynamic.so all cannot be found. I thought it might be the makefile.rules file, as I modified it to link some other object files, but even when compiling an example pin tool provided in the pin directory the same problem occurs. Does anyone know what the problem may be?

Answer (score 0):

To make ldd able to find them you can create a new conf file in /etc/ld.so.conf.d/ (/etc/ld.so.conf.d/pin.conf for instance). Then, inside this file, your need to provide paths to pin's dynamic libraries :

```
path_to_your_pin_folder/pin-3.0-76991-gcc-linux/ia32/runtime/pincrt
path_to_your_pin_folder/pin-3.0-76991-gcc-linux/intel64/runtime/pincrt/
path_to_your_pin_folder/pin-3.0-76991-gcc-linux/extras/xed-ia32/lib/
path_to_your_pin_folder/pin-3.0-76991-gcc-linux/extras/xed-intel64/lib/
path_to_your_pin_folder/pin-3.0-76991-gcc-linux/ia32/lib-ext/
path_to_your_pin_folder/pin-3.0-76991-gcc-linux/intel64/lib-ext/
```

Comment: Done this, but the SO's are still not found

Comment: @TypeKazt hi you have probably already solved this issue, but I had the same problem. After the creation of the configuration file you have to rebuild the loader cache with ldconfig
from the man page
"ldconfig creates the necessary links and cache to the most recent shared libraries found [...]
The *cache* is used by the run-time linker, ld.so or ld-linux.so"

Comment: @matt I can't find it now, but fortunately there was a related post to this problem. Also, no longer employed where this was a problem (happily employed elsewhere).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the relevant directories to your LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable.